# Device didn't get message from FCM

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I try to use FCM to send notification to my device but when i send it my device got nothing and i don't know did i do anything wrong ?
Plz tell me did i miss something ?

[image]

pubspec.yaml :

[image]

AndroidManifest.xml :

[image]

/android/build.gradle

[image]

/android/app/build.gradle
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you mixed up screenshots.. but I'll give it a try:

**build.gradle (App):**
Add

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'}
```

to the bottom.

**on iOS devices:**
You need to add the "Push Notification" Service to your Runnter Signing & Capabilities.

**In your Code:**
You need to initialise FCM

```
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onMessage: $message");
    _showItemDialog(message);
  },
  onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onLaunch: $message");
    _navigateToItemDetail(message);
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onResume: $message");
    _navigateToItemDetail(message);
  },
);
```

For more information you can visit [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) installation walkthrough

Comment: It's fine now but App not showing Notification receiving FCM when the app is Open

Comment: Therefore you have to fire a function in onMessage, f.e. showSnackbar, or whatsoever

Comment: It's done now I'm use local notification Thank for suggestion : D